# Transition in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am building a presentation and have to replace a part of a formula with another. Here is an MWE that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.1\textheight}
        $%
                blah = %
                        \only<1>{%
                        blah =
                        \begin{cases}
                                blah \\ blah
                        \end{cases}}
                        \only<2>{%
                                result
                        }
        $
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the formula wobbles while I would like to avoid that. How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\visible<>{}` is your friend. In contrast to `only`, `visible` reserves the space the cases would take on all slides and thus prevents "wobbling".

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  $
    blah =
    \only<1>{blah}
    \only<2>{result}
    \visible<1>{%
      =
      \begin{cases}
          blah \\ 
          blah
        \end{cases}
      }
    $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works indeed! I only used `only` and `onslide` but now `visible` has been added to my toolkit... Thanks!